# How can I delete the any rows in table application Angular 2?

Tags: angular

i won`t delete any row in my table on this method:

```
  deleteRowAdressForm(){
    this.rowDataMainForm.splice(1, 1);
}

  rowDataMainForm = [{
    name: '',
    email: '',
    tel: '',
    adress: '',
    delete: '',
}];
```

this method delete such first element in row, and i wont delete any rows, in my table

after update and use ChangeDetectorRef, but this dont work yet

this full code:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'tabletree',
    templateUrl:'app/tabletree.component.html',
})
export class TableTreeComponent{

constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef){

}


rowDataMainForm = [{
    name: '',
    email: '',
    tel: '',
    adress: '',
    delete: '',
}];

rowDataAdressForm = [{
    country: '',
    city: '',
    zipcode: '',
    street: '',
    delete: '',
}];

rowDataHomeForm = [{
    home: '',
    campus: '',
    province: '',
    area: '',
    delete: '',
}];

addRowMainForm(mainFormIndex){
    this.rowDataMainForm.push({
        name: '',
        email: '',
        tel: '',
        adress: '',
        delete: '',
    })
}

addRowAdressForm(){
    this.rowDataAdressForm.push({
        country: '',
        city: '',
        zipcode: '',
        street: '',
        delete: '',
    })
}

addRowHomeCampusProvinceAreaForm(){
    this.rowDataHomeForm.push({
        home: '',
        campus: '',
        province: '',
        area: '',
        delete: '',
    })
}

deleteRowAdressForm(addressFormIndex: number){
    this.rowDataMainForm.splice(addressFormIndex, 1);
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}

deleteRowStreetCityZipcodeForm(delRowStCZFormIndex: number){
    this.rowDataAdressForm.splice(delRowStCZFormIndex, 1);
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}

deleteRowHomeForm(homeFormIndex: number){
    this.rowDataHomeForm.splice(homeFormIndex, 1);
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}

}
```

and this html

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            Подразделение
        </h4>
    </div>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>email</th>
    <th>tel</th>
    <th>adress</th>
    <th>delete</th>
</tr>
<tr *ngFor="let row of rowDataMainForm; let mainFormIndex = index">
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
    <td>
        <div class="panel panel-default smaller">    
        <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>country</th>
                <th>city</th>
                <th>zipcode</th>
                <th>street</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr *ngFor="let newrow of rowDataAdressForm; let addressFormIndex = index">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="panel panel-default smaller">
                        <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>home</th>
                                    <th>campus</th>
                                    <th>province</th>
                                    <th>area</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tr *ngFor="let suchnewrow of rowDataHomeForm; let homeFormIndex = index">
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>
                                    <button (click)="deleteRowHomeForm(homeFormIndex)" type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="padding: 2px">Delete</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <div class="container-build">
                                <button (click)='addRowHomeCampusProvinceAreaForm()' type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="padding: 2px">Add row</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button (click)='deleteRowStreetCityZipcodeForm(delRowStCZFormIndex)' type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="padding: 2px">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <div class="container-build">
                <button (click)='addRowAdressForm()' type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="padding: 2px">Add row</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button (click)='deleteRowAdressForm(addressFormIndex)' type="button" class="btn btn-default">Delete</button>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="container-build">
        <button (click)='addRowMainForm(mainFormIndex)' type="button" class="btn btn-default">Add row</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You see no updates, because change detection is not running on nested objects in an array. You have two options:

1. Everytime you change something in the array assign it as a new object, because change detection only looks for reference changes.
2. Trigger change detection yourself (that's what I will show you, since the first option is self explanatory)

---

Import `ChangeDetectorRef`:

```js
import {ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
```

Inject `ChangeDetectorRef` into your component:

```js
constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, /* other injections here */) { 
    // ...
}
```

Use it in your method to detect changes:

```js
deleteRowAdressForm(rowNumber: number){
    this.rowDataMainForm.splice(rowNumber, 1);
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

---

**Changes you need to make to your template:**

On every `*ngFor` you use, you need to add the `index` variable like so:

```
*ngFor="let row of table; let rowIndex = index"
```

Then in your `(click)` deletion events you can leverage it like this:

```
(click)="deleteRow(rowIndex)"
```

I edited your template here with the usage, but don't forget to add the parameter to your delete functions like I did above!

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            Подразделение
        </h4>
    </div>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>email</th>
    <th>tel</th>
    <th>adress</th>
    <th>delete</th>
</tr>
<tr *ngFor="let row of rowDataMainForm; let mainFormIndex = index">
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
    <td>
        <div class="panel panel-default smaller">    
        <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>country</th>
                <th>city</th>
                <th>zipcode</th>
                <th>street</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr *ngFor="let newrow of rowDataAdressForm; let addressFormIndex = index">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="panel panel-default smaller">
                        <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>home</th>
                                    <th>campus</th>
                                    <th>province</th>
                                    <th>area</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tr *ngFor="let suchnewrow of rowDataHomeForm; let homeFormIndex = index">
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>
                                    <button (click)="deleteRowHomeForm(homeFormIndex)" type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="padding: 2px">Delete</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <div class="container-build">
                                <button (click)='addRowHomeCampusProvinceAreaForm()' type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="padding: 2px">Add row</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button (click)='deleteRowStreetCityZipcodeForm(/* ??? */)' type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="padding: 2px">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <div class="container-build">
                <button (click)='addRowAdressForm()' type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="padding: 2px">Add row</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button (click)='deleteRowAdressForm(addressFormIndex)' type="button" class="btn btn-default">Delete</button>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="container-build">
        <button (click)='addRowMainForm(mainFormIndex)' type="button" class="btn btn-default">Add row</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: when i add more rows in my table, and then delete any row (exm. 3), my row delete not 3, my row deleted 1 row

Comment: deleteRowAdressForm(addressFormIndex: number){
        this.rowDataMainForm.splice(addressFormIndex, 1);
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    } like this?

Comment: i update the code that you tell me, but it doesnt still working >< up my project, tell me, what i will do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a function parameter?

```
deleteAnyRowAdressForm(x){
    this.rowDataMainForm.splice(x, 1);
}
```

Comment: and now deleted only first element

Comment: Sure `deleteAnyRowAdressForm(1)`